# Leading injection

Tags: sql-injection

Are there known exploits where a query of the form:

```
select foo from bar where id = 6
```

can be turned into:

```
select * from select foo from bar where id = random stuff
```

It's clear that a badly formed app could easily allow injection
against the point in the query where the literal `6` is. I have
a case in hand where that was done, but also the extra
"`select * from`" was inserted at the front of the query at the
same time the literal at then end was attacked. I'm wondering
if this is either a generic known problem or if there are a class
of applications that are vulnerable in this way.

Comment: So you injected `random stuff` after `… id =` and somehow `select * from` got placed before `select foo from …`?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention if the input is not validated then adding what you like as the ID would be trivial.

With regards to the 'select * from ' prior to the main query then yes this could be possible.

Say for example you have

```
http://domain.com?column=foo&id=6
```

And that you were using $_GET['column'] (assumed PHP here but similar for other languages) to ascertain what column you required then all the person would need to do is adapt the url to be something like:

```
http://domain.com?column=*%20from%20select%20foo&id=6
```

If you used the following to create the SQL:

```
$sql = 'select ' . $_GET['column'] . ' from bar where id = ' . $_GET['id'];
```

SQL would then equate to the following string:

```
select * from select foo from bar where id = 6
```

Of course this would be a major error on the part of the programmer but I have seen a lot worse in the past. To mitigate this the programmer should check if the column name is contained within a whitelist. If it is then great, if not then do not honour the request or return the standard column.

With regards to any class of application that would be susceptible to such an attack. Your best bet would be to look around some of the vulnerability disclosure type sites. I would expect the main culprits however to be search pages within applications.

Comment: That’s not valid SQL.

Comment: @Gumbo The question hasn't asked wether the SQL is valid. It has merely asked how the SQL can end up having this form.

Answer (score 0):

Only if it's done on client-side applications. If you do it on the server-side, the only thing that is dangerous is XSS, which can be prevented by either "preparing" the statements or using PDO.

Validating what is put in the form (i.e. with PHP) is a good move too, to ban special characers like `*, <, >, %` etc. from fields that don't need them.